# Laravel 5.1 - Execute a PHP script in the Background

Tags: php, laravel, symfony-process

I have a web application written using Laravel 5.1 that runs a script when a user requests a certain page or clicks a button. This should activate the script in the background. I have tried this using Jobs & queues.

Here is my code chunk:
myjob.php

```
class myjob extends Job implements SelfHandling, ShouldQueue {
use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;

/**
 * Create a new job instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Execute the job.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function handle()
{
    //
    set_time_limit(0);
    $this->writeJobLogs('Error', 'Start Execution');
    //Job Processing Code
    $this->writeJobLogs('Error', 'End Execution');
}
}
```

Controller.php

```
class ManageController extends Controller {
    public function testJob(){
        $this->dispatch(new myjob());
    }
}
```

Job Processing Code is expected to take at least 10 minutes to get executed.
Now when I run the code it throws error after which is given below:

> [Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessTimedOutException]
>   The process ""C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php.exe" "artisan" queue:work  --queue="default" --delay=0 --memory=128 --sleep=3 --tries=0 --env="local"" exceeded
>    the timeout of 60 seconds.

& Job Processing Code is expected to be executed multiple times simultaneously, respective to the user requests. So I have a doubt regarding that if queues will be working fine or I have any other better choice. If so, please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

The Laravel Queue does not run processes in the background, rather gives you the ability to defer execution until a later time. Your script is timing out because it is exceeding the max execution time specified in your php.ini.

Comment: What would you suggest if I want to run process in background?

Comment: I believe the exec, or shell_exec, command(s) are what  you want to use to execute PHP code in the background. See this: https://florian.ec/articles/running-background-processes-in-php/

Comment: Here is a SO post on the subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45953/php-execute-a-background-process/45966#45966

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.. This posts show that they are using basic PHP exec & shell exec commands, Is there any other possible way for doing this in Laravel ?

Comment: Not that I know of, it's good old regular PHP to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

The first solution that springs to mind for me (may not be ideal for you) would be to set up the logging commands on seperate functions inside the controller, eg.

```
public function writeLog()
{
    // Do your logging here
}
```

and make AJAX calls to a route pointing at those functions, eg;

```
// Laravel Route
Route::get('ajaxDoStuff', 'FooController@writeLog');

// AJAX on Blade Template
$.ajax({
//all the usual stuff for an AJAX call
url: "/ajaxDoStuff"
});
```

That's how i'd do it anyway not sure if it's ideal for you?